# What is the difference between 'clever' and 'cunning'?

Tags: differences

It is common that these two words mean similar to each other, what is the difference?

Comment: Please explain which aspects of the meanings of the words you didn't understand, after you looked them up in a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

To my North American ear, "clever" means able to devise imaginative solutions to problems. Clever is generally at least a neutral term, and may be positive. To describe as Clever is typically to praise. "What a clever idea little Sally had for her birthday party!"

"Cunning" does mean essentially the same thing, but with an inference of possibly malicious self-interest and suggesting a zero-sum game. "The cunning fox tricked the Gingerbread boy so that he could eat him."